# Is xss exploits are possible with angular double braces

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to secure my application and i would like to know if an XSS exploit is possible with this type of code ?

Thanks

```
MyVar = ImportedValueFromDatabase
MyPage = __decorate([
        Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["m" /* Component */])({
            selector: 'page-details',
            template:'\n<ion-header>\n <ion-navbar>\n <ion-title center text-center style="padding:--px;" class="font-payback text-align_center color_white ">{{MyVar.PageTitle}}</ion-title>\n  </ion-navbar>\n</ion-header>\n',
        }),
        __param(5, Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["z" /* Inject */])(Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["_14"])(function () { return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__services_global_services__["a"]; }))),
        __metadata("design:paramtypes", 
            [__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__providers_my_provider__["a"],
            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_ionic_angular__["i"],
            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__angular_platform_browser__["c" /* DomSanitizer */]])
    ], MyPage);
return MyPage;
```

Comment: This question is more suitable for [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to code review